# How to loop over verticies in Gremlin and adding edge

Tags: titan, gremlin, rexster

I'm trying to figure out how to loop over verticies within a container and adding edges between the current vertice in the loop and a given vertice.

This is what I have so far:
This gives me an array of all vertice id's within the given container:

```
v=g.V('containerName','MyContainer').outE.inV.id
```

result:

```
{"results":[12,320004,280004,240004,200004,160004,120004,80004,40004],"success":true,"version":"2.4.0","queryTime":35.089565}
```

Now I want to loop/iterate over all the id's in this array, get the vertice of the id and add an edge between a given vertice and the current vertice in the loop.

Anyone that knows how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `sideEffect` that adds the new edges.

With the toy tinker [graph](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Property-Graph-Model):

```
g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
```

let's assume you want to link peter to all neighbors of marko (out only)

```
givenVertex = g.V('name','peter').next()
g.V('name','marko').out.sideEffect{g.addEdge(givenVertex,it, 'yourLabel')}
```

verify result:

```
g.V('name','peter').out.name
==>lop // lop appears twice because edge peter -> lop was present previous to operation
==>lop
==>vadas
==>josh
```

Comment: Hi, i tried doing what you suggested but when I looked at the result of doing g.V('containerName','Acontainer').out.containerName in my case I got {"results":[null,..,null],"success":true,"version":"2.4.0","queryTime":33.366562}

Comment: It seems like the edges have been created, I could verify the result by doing g.V('contaninerName','Acontainer').outE

Comment: Hmm might be a problem with rexster. I tried my solution only with a TinkerGraph. Nevertheless, you showed in your question how to fetch the ids of a vertex. I guess you could loop over the ids, fetch the vertex again, and apply the sideEffect. `g.V('containerName','MyContainer').outE.inV.id` should be iterable. Maybe try something like `g.V('containerName','MyContainer').outE.inV.id.sieEffect{g.addEdge(g.v(<givenVertexId>).next(), g.v(it).next(), 'yourLabel')}`

Comment: Ah ok … just wanted to ask you this ;)

Comment: Note that the Gremlin shell iterates all your statements automatically. In Rexster you have to iterate explicitly: ```g.V('name','marko').out().sideEffect{givenVertex.addEdge('yourLabel', it)}.iterate()```